# Displaying custom metadata in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

I was able to add custom aspects to documents in order to set custom properties.
The next step for me would be to have a local instance of Alfresco displaying the custom properties and having them editable so that users can change their values via the web pages.

There's [a good link on wiki.alfresco](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Displaying_Custom_Metadata) that describes just that and I followed the instructions, but it's not working for me.

In short, I added a custom aspect called my:customAspect like this:

```
AlfrescoDocument alfDoc = ... // get existing document
alfDoc.addAspect("P:my:customAspect");

// set additional properties
Map<String, Object> propertiesEnum = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put("my:score", 152);
...
alfDoc.updateProperties(updateProperties);
```

The properties were correctly added and I can see their values either programatically or by using Apache Chemistry Workbench desktop client.

In order to have the additional properties visible in Alfresco Web client, I updated the web-client-config-custom.xml file by setting:

```
   <config evaluator="aspect-name" condition="my:customAspect">
      <property-sheet>
         <show-property name="my:score"/>
      </property-sheet>
   </config>
```

Unfortunately, I can't see this property listed in the Alfresco web (including the /share one) for the documents on whom I added the custom aspect.

Maybe I'm missing something, maybe there are some other xml files that should be updated.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Will your users be using Alfresco Share or Alfresco Explorer? You hopefully are aware that you must configure each of these two clients separately, i.e. you cannot use the same config for both.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, viewing custom aspect properties is not supported in Share.
If you need to show these props you have to include them in the form defined for a particular type.
You could use this little [help](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/forms-aspect-display.html).

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, Share does support custom aspect properties, we use it in all our Share projects. Here is the link to one of our examples: http://snag.gy/MD47z.jpg

Comment: Maybe i haven't explained, I didn't say that share doesn't support custom aspect properties, But YOU CANNOT DEFINE A FORM FOR A SPECIFIC ASPECT, you need to define a form for a specified type and include your cutom aspect properties, so if the node has that aspect, these props will be shown

Comment: thaks for your answers! @Alch3mi5t, can you upload your custom .xml settings for the .jpg form?

Comment: Sorry @alaeddine.nasri, I didn't understand what were you saying. Anyhow, here is the link of my share config,search for the <config evaluator="node-type" condition="cli:cartellaClinica" > http://pastebin.com/QuVf2uKa

Comment: Actually it *is* possible to configure the display of properties based on an aspect rather than a type - see [this post](http://loftux.com/2010/02/11/alfresco-forms-for-share/) for an example.

Comment: there's a very good link here on how to create and have aspects displayed in Alfresco Share http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-content/content-article-2ed.pdf

Comment: yes, your solutions definitely work for some needs, but doesn't work for this example : I have a customAspect and I have configured its form. Now I want every node ( af all possible types ) that has this aspect to show me the configured properties. I need to do that without configuring Type display form.
I hope you are understanding me, Even we could configure the aspect properties alone but eventually we have to set them in the type configuration as mentioned above by Alch3mi5t.